# Making a special rotating animation of a group of pictures

Tags: javascript, animation

I am building a new web server and I'd like to add some animation in it.

I have a group of pictures (3 at the moment it can change) and I'd like to add an animation of it to rotate the group of pictures, like : 
- The left picture becomes smaller and moves to the left. At a moment, it disappears and appears again of the right. 
- The right picture becomes bigger and moves to the left. Once at the center, it becomes smaller etc.

Am I clear ? It's quite difficult to explain ...

I made a [Ridiculous draw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJQG0.png) if it helps !

I am not asking for the solution (but if you have it it's fine !) but a way to do it (jquery ?) ! :)

Thanks

Comment: You are looking for slider/carousel plugins. Here's a link to something which might suit your needs - https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Smooth-Card-Carousel-jQuery-CSS3/ - or Slick slider using Center Mode - https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! 
Indeed it is a mixed between your both links. But how to make them move automaticaly ?

Comment: I've pointed you in the right direction, now it's just a matter of reading the documentation :)

Comment: You're right ! Thanks :)